# Python3, subprocess.Popen, how to redirect stdout to a file and read it

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I m running the following snippet of code

```
    path_to_output_file = 'myoutput.txt'

    myoutput = open(path_to_output_file,'w+')

    pro= subprocess.Popen('/usr/local/bin/myExecutable', stdout=myoutput)


    with open(path_to_output_file) as f:
        line= f.readline()
        while line:
            line = f.readline()
            print("Line ".line.strip())
```

File myoutput.txt is created and updated, i can see all the stdout lines
myExec file is running in the background and generates log info in the file

Problem:
i can't read any line of the file, it looks like file is empty but i can open with any text editor.

Any advice?
Thanks

Comment: Use `subprocess` convenience methods (such as `call`) https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio. If you want to use `Popen` constructure, you need to wait for the process e.g. with `pro.comunicate()` https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Comment: That's the point, I can't wait til the process terminates as I need to spawn a thread and check the stdout some now and then for some log information. If you can suggest any alternative way to spawn a process and check the stdout or redirect the output to a file I would appreciate.

Comment: It appears that you are reading the file only once, just after it was created. Depending on what you want to do, you might want wrap the `with open` to `while True:` to open and read the file multiple times. Also consider to write some condition to break the loop.